# html button not embedded within a parent div

Tags: html, css, button, element, styling

I have this code I wrote to recreate a basic site home page:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 550px;
  width: 850px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

header :first-child {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

header>div {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  height: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <img src="" />
    <h2>Taking booleaners from A to B</h2>
    <div>
      <button>Prenota</button>
      <button>Termina Prenotazione</button>
      <button>Accendi Luci</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

The problem is that the buttons get shown below the div despite being its children and I can't understand why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: It is so unclear what exactly do you want?

Comment: @decpk the buttons should fit inside the green bar

Comment: It is just a typo,  There shouldn't be any space between `header` and `:first-child`. It should be `header:first-child` instead of `header :first-child`

Answer (score 0):

This bit

```css
    header :first-child {
        height: 80px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

should be

```css
    header > :first-child {
        height: 80px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

The current selector applies to all children, and their children. `>` specifies only the children of the specified parent.

Result:
[image: Corrected Result]

Comment: Awesome, remember to mark a question as solved by accepting an answer :)
(checkmark at the left)

Comment: @decpk using > works fine while just writing header:first-child is messing up the image idk why

Comment: BTW, This is not the correct answer. It is just a typo. [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Comment: @JohnPaulR yeah imma accept it as soon as the site lets me ahah

Comment: Then there must be something else that is causing the problem. But this is not how you should proceed. `header > :first-child ` doesn't mean anything at all

Comment: @decpk could the image be inheriting its height and width by the div father of header? I didn't write it in the question but it has defined height and width

Comment: If it somehow works doesn't mean it is the right solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233255/discussion-between-decpk-and-newbie).

Comment: This is not true. `header > :first-child` is identical to `header > *:first-child`.
"If a [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#universal-selector) represented by * [...] is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the * may be omitted and the universal selector's presence implied."